# MDX Color expression based on another Measure value using SSAS

Tags: colors, ssas, mdx, cube, measure

I have two measures in my cube - the first shows summed revenue and the second data availability (indicates how many percent data do we still) miss. Is there any possibility to color summed revenue based on data availability?

For example: *for one organization the summed revenue is 400$ and data availability is less than 80% - in this case I would like to display this 400$ in cube as a gray. When data availability = 100%, I want to display this revenue as black.*

Thank you all for your help.

Regards,
Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the `FORE_COLOR` property. Here is an example with a calculated member:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[colored revenue] AS 
     [Measures].[summed revenue],
         FORE_COLOR= IIf([Measures].[data availability] < 80, 5066061, 16777215)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. And is it possible to set color based on measure calculations ? I've tried to set the color in this way:
IIF([Measures].[Count All]/[Measures].[Count Available] > 50, 0 , 5066061), but it does not work.